# Eclipse not showing Android SDK after Copy-Paste Update

Tags: android, eclipse

I had eclipse installed and working perfectly with Android SDK. Everything was working fine. I tried the 'Check for Updates' and it gave me this error:

**Cannot complete the install because of a conflicting dependency.**
**Eclipse SDK**

It refused to update so I decided to download the latest package and update it manually by overwriting the eclipse folder.

Now, eclipse is running update but its not showing ANY of my installed packages :( No Android SDK, no Google WDT etc.

Please help! I have to work! :( How can I fix it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You just need to uninstall and reinstall android. It seems you forced eclipse to use update even though it complained that **conflicting dependency**.

Comment: Uninstall Android? You mean just the ADT plugin right? Or the whole SDK and everything?

Comment: OK its working now. I just deleted the eclipse folder and extracted a fresh copy in its place. After that, I just installed the ADT Plugin. The SDKs and everything else was already detected.

Thanks for the help :)